# How to get compiler to ignore -Wfatal-errors temporarily

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-errors, arm64

```
SystemDateAndTime.cpp:205:14: error: ‘stime’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘ftime’?
  205 |    if( -1 == stime( &systime ) )
      |              ^~~~~
      |              ftime
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors
```

How to ask the compiler to proceed. Is there something similar to -Wno-error (with which we ask compiler to not consider warnings as errors) , perhaps -Wno-fatal-errors ?

I know that this code will compile with linaro-aarch64-2017.08-gcc7.1 (and g++). I am trying to compile the same with gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc (and g++) only so that I can make use of  -fsanitize=address,undefined for Address Sanitizer.  So I am desperate for the compilation to proceed really !

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you include `<time.h>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 - I tried it to see if i could get past it, but #include <time.h> isn't working

Comment: @Bart - Even if i gave one , no one is going to try and compile with two different compilers to see the problem. This, i feel, is a straight case of trying to avoid a fatal error just to get past compilation using the 10.3 instead of 7.1. There may be more such errors that come up because of changing the compiler. It would be time consuming to fix each and every one. It would be easy if I could just ignore these errors and get past compilation. I am only keen to try -fsanitize option using gdb which unfortunately is not supported by 7.1

Comment: `#if 0` the problematic part as workaround, you cannot get executable from code with errors.

Comment: From what I understand `-fsanitize` is a runtime option and so even if you "ignore" build errors you wont be able to run it and use the sanitiser.

Comment: @MikeVine  - I have just managed to compile the binary with -fsanitize option using gcc-10.3. That was the only error luckily so didn't have to do anything much. But are you saying I won't be able to make use of the binary with debugging symbols and sanitizer thus generated ? I am having a separate issue where the size of the binary has become enormous. So trying to cut it down

Comment: The point is that if you want to get a binary that runs, which is the whole point if you want to test the sanitizer, then you can't just "ignore" the error with the missing declaration - you have to tell the compiler what to do instead.  Emit the call anyway, with an implicit declaration (understanding that it might fail to link)?  Skip the entire section of code?  And the best way to do that is to actually modify the code so that it says what you want, e.g. `#if 0` out the block.